# find an array based on its property array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

im trying to get an array based on its element id of array of object and the structure is looks like this

```json
{"data": [
        {
            "id": 46,
            "name": "shsjks",
            "desc": "ehejej",
            "code": "hshsbsb",
            "activation_type": 1,
            "detail": "[{\"id\": 413, \"name\": \"A\"}, {\"id\": 416, \"name\": \"B\"}]",
        },
        {
            "id": 47,
            "name": "hhksns",
            "desc": "benemne",
            "code": "gevewk",
            "activation_type": 1,
            "detail": "[{\"id\": 419, \"name\": \"C\"}, {\"id\": 423, \"name\": \"D\"}]"
        },
    ]}
```

im trying to get the data based on the detail id and what i did

```js
let arr = a.data.filter(x => {
    return (JSON.parse(x.detail).filter(x => x.id === 419))
});
// returned all instead of first element of the array
```

i want it to returned

```
// filter where id 419
{
  "id": 47,
  "name": "shjks",
  "detail": "[{\"id\": 419, \"name\": \"C\"}, {\"id\": 423, \"name\": \"D\"}]"
  ....
}
```

Comment: You probably want `.length > 0` after the second filter, or replace it with `.some`

Comment: If you want the first element of the array, why do you call the result `arr`? It will not be an array, right?

Comment: Adam Smith - please see working answer below using .some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.filter` will not perform a map. The return value of its callback function is supposed to just indicate whether the array element (from the top level array) should be included or not. So you should return a falsy value when you don't want an array to be included. As `.some` returns a boolean, that is a perfect candidate method to use for that purpose. And if you expect only one match, then `.find` is more appropriate than `.filter`:

```js
let a = {"data": [{"id": 46,"name": "shsjks","desc": "ehejej","code": "hshsbsb","activation_type": 1,"detail": "[{\"id\": 413, \"name\": \"A\"}, {\"id\": 416, \"name\": \"B\"}]",},{"id": 47,"name": "hhksns","desc": "benemne","code": "gevewk","activation_type": 1,"detail": "[{\"id\": 419, \"name\": \"C\"}, {\"id\": 423, \"name\": \"D\"}]"},]}

let result = a.data.find(x => JSON.parse(x.detail).some(x => x.id === 419));

console.log(result);
```

If you want the `details` to remain parsed in the result, then first perform a  `map`:

```js
let a = {"data": [{"id": 46,"name": "shsjks","desc": "ehejej","code": "hshsbsb","activation_type": 1,"detail": "[{\"id\": 413, \"name\": \"A\"}, {\"id\": 416, \"name\": \"B\"}]",},{"id": 47,"name": "hhksns","desc": "benemne","code": "gevewk","activation_type": 1,"detail": "[{\"id\": 419, \"name\": \"C\"}, {\"id\": 423, \"name\": \"D\"}]"},]}

let result = a.data.map(x => ({ ...x, detail: JSON.parse(x.detail)}))
                   .find(x => x.detail.some(x => x.id === 419));

console.log(result);
```

If you are only interested in the `id` key itself, then perform a `.flatMap` to first collect all parsed `detail` arrays, so you get one array with all the details, and then `.find` the element you need:

```js
let a = {"data": [{"id": 46,"name": "shsjks","desc": "ehejej","code": "hshsbsb","activation_type": 1,"detail": "[{\"id\": 413, \"name\": \"A\"}, {\"id\": 416, \"name\": \"B\"}]",},{"id": 47,"name": "hhksns","desc": "benemne","code": "gevewk","activation_type": 1,"detail": "[{\"id\": 419, \"name\": \"C\"}, {\"id\": 423, \"name\": \"D\"}]"},]}

let result = a.data.flatMap(x => JSON.parse(x.detail)).find(x => x.id === 419);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: alternatively you can use this: `let arr = a.data.filter(x => JSON.parse(x.detail).filter(x => x.id === 419).length);`

Comment: my bad, ill edit my question
i want to returned it the whole array (id, name, desc, detail,...)  
but i get the gist of it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this.

```
let arr = a.data.filter(x => {
    return (JSON.parse(x.detail).filter(x => x.id === 419).length)
});
```

Array.filter returns `[]` if there is no value present. So when you return the array itself it is never considered as false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the first filter need to return a boolean value (filter or not)

This will work for u:

```js
const test = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 46,
      name: 'shsjks',
      desc: 'ehejej',
      code: 'hshsbsb',
      activation_type: 1,
      detail: '[{"id": 413, "name": "A"}, {"id": 416, "name": "B"}]',
    },
    {
      id: 47,
      name: 'hhksns',
      desc: 'benemne',
      code: 'gevewk',
      activation_type: 1,
      detail: '[{"id": 419, "name": "C"}, {"id": 423, "name": "D"}]',
    },
  ],
};

const arr = test.data.find((x) => JSON.parse(x.detail).some((d) => d.id === 419));

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));
```